# Piped commands altering standard output?

Tags: linux, shell, pipe

I've tried three different "alias" functions to make an image show from the command line given an argument. Can someone point me in the right direction towards figuring out why the input is handled differently than when I just feed the URL to the final command?

```
function xkcd() {pandoc -f html -t plain https://xkcd.com/"$1"/ | grep *.png | display;}
function xkcd() {pandoc -f html -t plain https://xkcd.com/"$1"/ | grep *.png | w3m;}
function xkcd() {pandoc -f html -t plain https://xkcd.com/"$1"/ | grep *.png | open;}
function xkcd() {pandoc -f html -t plain https://xkcd.com/"$1"/ | grep *.png | eog;}

#where $1 is a number in the range of values present in the site's structure
```

When I run w3m by itself with image URL as argument it pops open a small cropped imagemagick window with the image in it (desired result of function).
When it runs receiving the URL from the pipe (seemingly), it opens a page that just has the URL text printed on it.

Running display worked fine as well, then with pipe gave me the error:

```
display-im6.q16: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/575.
```

open gave me its' help dialogue:

```
xdg-open - opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application

Synopsis

xdg-open { file | URL }

xdg-open { --help | --manual | --version }

Use 'man xdg-open' or 'xdg-open --manual' for additional info.
```

eog opened a blank window for both, so not useful in this endeavor.

I can't tell whether I'm doing something wrong, expecting too much from the pipe, or have some simple syntax bug that I can't identify, as I'm still learning, but it's driving me crazy.

```
function xkcd() { pandoc -t https://xkcd.com/"$1" | grep ".png" | cat; }
```

returns the image URL as expected.

```
function xkcd() { pandoc -t https://xkcd.com/"$1" | grep ".png" | echo; }
```

returns a blank line, I'm guessing this is the crux of the issue, but am hoping someone can explain it to me or point me in the right direction to understand what's going on under the hood here? TIA.

PS: using bash on debian bullseye, if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command line arguments **are not** standard input/output. When you run `eog foobar` with the URL as a command-line argument, it receives that parameter in a completely different way than if you used `echo foobar | eog` – unlike *reading* data from stdin as a 'file', the program is directly given a list of arguments as the 'argv' array.

There is no expectation that programs would treat both identically; indeed, most programs are expected to treat them *differently*. For example, ImageMagick's `display` expects to read raw image data from stdin, rather than filenames, whereas EoG doesn't care about stdin at all. (And of course, in your own example, `grep` is able to read text from stdin *and* take the regex pattern from its command line.)

When you have a pipeline and want to use its output as a program's command-line parameters, the most common way of doing so is the `xargs` tool:

```
echo https://xkcd.com/1168/ | xargs -d '\n' w3m
```

Alternatively, use the shell's `$(…)` or `` `…` `` operator to capture the program's output into a variable:

```
url=$(pandoc this | grep that) && w3m "$url"
```

```
display "$(pandoc https://xkcd | grep '\.png')"
```

---

Beware also that 1) `grep` accepts regular expressions, not shell wildcards; 2) unquoted wildcards are expanded by the shell and aren't passed "raw" to the program, unless the expansion happens to fail.

So if you use `| grep *.png` and have some PNG files in the current directory, your function will instead end up running `| grep foo.png` which will not produce the correct output.

If you quote the parameter to prevent expansion and use `| grep "*.png"`, it still won't work – it's not even a valid regular expression (in regexes, `*` is a modifier and needs *something* before it).

You want to use either `grep ".*\.png"` or just `grep "\.png"` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I mistyped the grep argument. I had put `grep ".png"` What do the ".*\" and the "\" in `grep "\.png"` do in terms of the RE?