# Can't open text file with fzf from terminal

Tags: bash, terminal

I am using this command to open a text file from the terminal on macOS:

```
fzf | open
```

But whenever I do I just get the output that results when you execute the `open` command by itself (without any arguments). Which leads me to believe `fzf` isn't returning a result. But when I do `fzf` on its own and select the same file it *does* output the path to the selected file. So I'm confused as to why the above command isn't opening the selected file as expected.

How can I open a file selected using `fzf`?

Comment: Why is `fzf` a shell variable and while are you attempting to do what seems to be passing `~`, which is a directory, to it? What is the value of `$fzf`?

Comment: `fzf` isn't a shell variable. The `$` is the default leading character in the terminal prompt; and preceding it is the the default location of the current directory — which in this case is the home directory (`~`).

Comment: Then it's better to edit the question and just show the command that you used and not the preceding characters in the terminal in order to avoid confusion. Even if you wanted to include it, there is usually a space between the character and the input of the terminal unless you've done something to alter your terminal. What file are you selecting? After what you've stated, your command is just piping `fzf` into `open` with no file to be found.

Comment: @shoe there should be a space after the `$` or `#` prompt

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Command line arguments are not standard input/output."](https://superuser.com/a/1712927/432690)